# Not able to get Current ViewController inside applicationWillResignActive

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a storyboard based Single View App;

I have 3 `ViewControllers` on my Storyboard linked to 3 `ViewController` classes in the code;

I browse between `ViewControllers` by doing this:

```
UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
MenuViewController* mainMenu = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vcMainMenu"];

mainMenu.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:mainMenu animated:YES];
```

Now I need to access different `UIcontrols` on the `applicationWillResignActive` from the current active `ViewController`, I will access different controls depending of the `ViewController`, I'm trying to accomplish this by doing:

```
if ([self.window.rootViewController isKindOfClass:[LowProfileViewController class]])
{
    NSLog(@"here!");
}
```

But it always returns the `rootViewController`. How Can I get the current displayed `rootViewController` from `applicationWillResignActive`?

Please, Incorporate `NavigationController` is not an option...

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try this -

1. Make An `AppDelegate` `@property` (i.e. `currentModelViewController`)

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *currentModelViewController;
   ```
2. For each `ViewController`s in `viewDidAppear` or in `viewWillAppear`

   ```
   appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   appDelegate.currentModelViewController = self;
   ```

Now this will work

```
if ([self.currentModelViewController isKindOfClass:[LowProfileViewController class]])
{
    NSLog(@"here!");
}
```