# Accessing the top view controller from the app delegate

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I need my AppDelegate to be able to obtain a pointer to my current displayed view controller (have explored `visibleViewController` for navigation views, but a more generic version would be better) and read the state from my object instances for use in `applicationWillResignActive`.

My attempt at this had me initializing new objects, and those are just empty. I need the object's state at any point in runtime.

I figure I could make a singleton class that parallels my objects, which I can call on from the app delegate, but that seems clunky and wordy. I also thought of making the view controller a delegate for AppDelegate, but that seems even worse.

I know I'm probably overlooking the obvious, but I must be wording my search wrong because I can't get clarity. I've searched Stack Overflow for 10 minutes and skimmed the view controller and appdelegate docs.

How can I access an object's property values at runtime from the app delegate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not able to get Current ViewController inside applicationWillResignActive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409882/not-able-to-get-current-viewcontroller-inside-applicationwillresignactive) There's no tricks here. You make an object "in scope" as far as another object is concerned by giving the second a pointer (via a property) to the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on exactly what your view controllers do and how you want your app to restore its state when reopened, the `AppDelegate` should have minimal involvement.

Instead you should consider having the view controllers that are appropriate observe the `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` notification and each perform their own storage of their own state. When the app reopens, the `AppDelegate` just restores the root view controller, the root VC then checks if it needs to restore anything, and on in a chain until all data is restored. This keeps all of the logic and the data storage modular and segregated.

If you really:

> need the object's state at any point in runtime

Then you have a different design problem and you need to break things down. The `AppDelegate` should be used for specific tasks, it has a role to play in `applicationWillResignActive` but that role should not be to manage 100% of the work that needs to be done.

Comment: Wain, when you say the view controllers should 'observe' are specifically suggesting the use of KVO?

Comment: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification is a notification posted by NSNotificationCenter. A view controller can add itself as an observer. This is not KVO.